# How to enqueue items into akka.net queue source

Tags: akka.net-streams

After creating a queue source in akka.net streams, how can I add items to the queue? There is no Enqueue, Add or Offer method in created object.

```
Source<int, ISourceQueueWithComplete<int>> source = 
   Source.Queue<int>(100, OverflowStrategy.Backpressure);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's OfferAsync, you can have an example at unit tests, e.g. https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/master/src/core/Akka.Streams.Tests/Dsl/QueueSourceSpec.cs